# Setting default values in sliders using interact

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to set a default value for a slider using interact in a jupyter notebook, based on [this](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) documentation.

While the values for min, max, and step work well,

```
from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=(5,20,5))
```

I cannot pass an initial default value 15, I always get an error trying to do:

```
from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=(5,20,5,15))
```

or

```
interact(f, x=(min=5,max=20,step=5,value=15))
```

The error message reads:

> ValueError: (5, 20, 5, 15) cannot be transformed to a widget

or

> Syntax error

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Python 3.4 on jupyter notebook, using Linux. I got this to work:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets


def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=5,max=20,step=5,value=15));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. And one can do a `print("Value: ",x)` within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Bokeh Documentation!

[Click me!](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#userguide-interaction-widgets)

Transform this code for your needs:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

output_file("slider.html")

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Stuff")

show(widgetbox(slider))
```

I hope this helps you. I am on the way. Just tell me if you need more support.

Kind regards,
Fabian

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it seems that the problem I have is based on handing over the slider parameters to a function. I have no problem in directly using the value parameter in a slider call.